# Measuring .7 volts on pin 2 and 0.0 on the rest when setting all pins low

Tags: pins

Having my Arduino Nano 328P disconnected from any circuitry and setting all pins to `pinMode(OUTPUT)` and writing `LOW` to (almost) all the pins, when I connect my multimeter to every output pin and the Arduino ground, I measure 0.7 volts on pin 2 and 0.0 volts on 3 to 19. Here I mean the pin numbers on the edge of the Nano, not the processor pins.

For my project it worked out fine because I needed those 0.0 and not the 0.7, but I'm afraid it suddenly might not be pin 2 that's 0.7 in the future and my circuit would fail.

> Why is there this one pin giving 0.7 instead of 0.0 and how can I make sure or argue that it will only be pin 2 that gives 0.7?

EDIT as per request, the full test code is below.

```
void setup() {
  for (int i=1;i<20;i++){
  pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop() {
  for (int i=1;i<20;i++){
    digitalWrite(i, HIGH);  
  }
    delay(3000);               
    for (int i=1;i<20;i++){
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);   
    }
    delay(3000);               
}
```

Comment: What voltage is your 328P running at? At 5V, 0.7V is still perfectly within specification (0.9V max V[OL]).

Comment: @Majenko I'm not sure exactly, I'm running it via a phone wall adapter which outputs 5V/1A which I think should be enough, how could I check if it really is? If you think it's the voltage provided, I'll check when powering it via my laptop.

Comment: No, you misunderstand. There are two options for running the boards like the Micro / Nano, etc - 5V or 3.3V. The V[OL] specification changes depending on supply voltage, and that is fixed by the board, not the PSU. It sounds like you have a 5V version anyway, so the output is within specification.

Comment: @Majenko Ah yeah I knew about the 5V-3.3V difference, but I have the 5V one. I confirmed that V[OH] is 4.7V for every pin. But where did you find the maximum V[OL] is 0.9? I had googled before asking the question to find that value but didn't find results. Do I understand correctly that that means you just know the voltage output is between 0 and 0.9 and you cannot guess the exact value?

Comment: The value is in the datasheet, page 313, table 30-1.

Comment: @Majenko I'm a bit confused which datasheet, I mean there is no Nano datasheet right? I looked into the ATMega 328P sheet but can't find it there.

Comment: http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf

Comment: @Majenko Oh that's curious, I was looking at a 328P datasheet but a different one. Anyway, I see what you mean, the 0.0 or 0.7 is just some kind of stable noise. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll think of a way to adapt my circuit to that.

Comment: You were probably looking at the summary sheet.

Comment: @Majenko To summarize 660 pages into 444 seems weird to me, haha. http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_datasheet.pdf

Comment: @Majenko I think you should post your comments as one answer.

Comment: Can you post your code please? I personally like to see code, not a description of it.

Comment: @NickGammon Of course, I'll do that immediately next time. I included it now.

Comment: `writing LOW to all the pins` - all pins except pin D0, eh? Your question is a bit non-specific. Do you mean pin D2 on the edge of an Arduino Uno? Or pin 2 on the actual Atmega328P chip? Pin 2 on the chip itself is D0 in the IDE, which you have not written LOW to.

Comment: @NickGammon Ah I didn't know those number differed, I meant pin 2 on the edge of the Nano (not Uno) all the time, that I didnt include pin 0 shouldnt matter as I skipped pin 0 and 1 alltogether. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, thanks to Majenko: these values fall within the expected voltage output range of 0-0.9V, and you cannot be certain it will stay this way. See the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf) page 313.